Finding the probability of getting the correct code for a $4$-digit lock, knowing it only has even digits without repeating
The problem says:

What is the probability of getting the correct code for a 4 "wheel" lock, where each wheel has the digits 0 to 9. Knowing also that the correct code only has even digits without repeating?

The informal expression on which I based the demonstration was "first you have to choose one of the four wheels and then you have to choose one of the even digits, and then you have to continue." So my answer was (I formalized this):
$$\require{cancel} \left(\frac{1}{\cancel{4}}\right) \cdot \left(\frac{5}{10}\right) \cdot \left(\frac{1}{\cancel{3}}\right) \cdot \left(\frac{\cancel{4}}{10}\right) \cdot \left(\frac{1}{{\cancel{2}}}\right) \cdot \left(\frac{\cancel{3}}{10}\right) \cdot \left(\frac{1}{1}\right) \cdot \left(\frac{\cancel{2}}{10}\right) = \frac{5}{10^4}$$
But unfortunately the correct answer is $\frac{5!}{10^4}$, because the informal "correct" expression does not include the part of "first choose one of the 4 wheels".
What did I do wrong?

Can't follow your thinking.  There are $5$ even digits,  so there are $5$ choices for the first,  then $4$ choices for the second,  and so on.

But that means that there are $5!$ ways to write the four digit code,  so your chance of guessing it correctly is $\frac 1{5!}$.

is the number of correct permutations divided by the number of total permutations? Anyway, I would like to know why my answer is wrong, or why I should remove from the informal expression the phrase "first you have to choose one of the 4 digits"

I can't follow your thinking.

I mean, to do proofs in mathematics you must first express an idea in informal words. That formalized idea is a rigorous mathematical proof. Now, the correct answer was one (which was associated with an informal idea), and my answer (which I thought was correct) was associated with another informal idea. The question was, why was my informal idea incorrect?

I can't follow your informal idea.  What does it mean to say "first you have to choose one of the four digits."  Which four digits?  There are $5$ even digits.    Do you mean one of the four digits of the code?  Well, why not just choose a $4$ digit code made from distinct even digits?  What difference does it make what order you build the code in?

To be clear, the officially "correct" answer is also wrong, at least as I understand the problem.  There are $5!$ possible codes that satisfy the conditions, so your chance of guessing correctly is $\frac 1{5!}$.  I don't see what $10^4$ has to do with it...most of those are codes that don't pass the tests so they aren't relevant.

You should copy the exact text of the problem, I think you did not. The way everyone arrives to $5!$ is strange, with this text, I would arrive to $5^4$ instead of $5!$

I just edited the text

Generally, in probability, the informal idea is to count how many total options, and then, separately, count how many options are considered as success.  Here, the official answer is not correct, it is the answer to this question : if we generate randomly a code, what is the probability to obtain a code with 4 distinct digits, all of them are even.

This question is not very well worded, in my opinion. It's not clear to me who exactly knows that the combination is some permutation of the even digits. Is it the guesser? Is it the problem answerer? (They are not necessarily the same person.) Does "getting the correct code" mean unlock the lock, or does it mean randomly select a code that satisfies the condition (as the official answer seems to suggest)? It's a mess. ¶ Also, use MathJax. It's not clear whether "5!/(10 power 4)" means $5!/10^4$.

Also, my totally unsolicited advice is to focus less on "informal" vs "formal" and just get used to doing these questions, ideally with questions that are less ambiguously worded. Out of curiosity, where did this question come from?

The implication in your informal idea is that there's a specific nonstandard order in which the correct code has to be described: the correct code is something like

0 is the 2nd digit, 4 is the 4th digit, 2 is the 3rd digit, 2 is the 1st digit,

such that saying

2 is the 1st digit, 0 is the 2nd digit, 2 is the 3rd digit, 4 is the 4th digit

instead would be incorrect, even though both of them describe the code "2024". Then, you would indeed need to include factors like $\frac14$ that you choose the correct first position to enter, $\frac13$ that you choose the correct second position to enter, and so forth.
But that's not the case by the normal reading of the question: if "2024" is a correct code, then describing its digits in any order is fine. So your answer is off by a factor of $4!$, which makes sense: if you specify the digits in a random order, then there's a $\frac1{4!}$ chance that you specify them in the "correct order".

It's also pointed out in the comments that both $\frac{5!}{10^4}$ and $\frac{1}{4!} \cdot \frac{5!}{10^4}$ are trying to find the probability that a randomly chosen sequence of any four digits is actually going to have four even, non-repeating digits in it.
That's not quite what the probability of getting the correct code on the wheel lock would be, as the question is quoted. If you do not know anything about the lock, then there are $10^4$ combinations, so the probability of guessing the right one would be $\frac1{10^4}$. If you know that the correct combination has four even numbers, all different, then there are $5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2$ or $5!$ such combinations, so the probability of guessing the right one would be $\frac1{5!}$.

Are you saying that there is a tacit non-random order for the code (first one, then the other, etc.), and therefore, for the purposes of the question, it is not necessary to put 1/4!? But in real life would my answer be correct?

Maths is a way to represent real life. So, correct answer in maths is correct answer in real life.

@Max My answer applies to both real life and "the purposes of this question". You do not need to assume there is a tacit non-random order; on the contrary, with any order, the answer of $\frac{5!}{10^4}$ is correct. It is your answer of $\frac1{4!} \cdot \frac{5!}{10^4}$ that assumes the existence of some unknown order in which the digits must be specified or they are wrong.

In the comment, Misha, you say $5!\div10^4$ is correct, but in the last line of your answer, you say $1/(5!)$ is correct.

@GerryMyerson The last line of my answer was added later. But my best guess is actually that $5!/10^4$ is correct when the question is correctly quoted, I just wanted to cover all the bases.

Personally, I think that the right answer has to be $~1/(5!),~$ because of the specific wording of the problem.  When there is a conflict between the (presented) problem's explicit wording, and the (reasonably) inferred problem composer's intent, I feel that the MathSE responder must give priority to the explicit wording.  Then, the responder can (for example) add an Addendum to explore possible other interpretations.  Such an approach is reasonable, because it is common (but by no means a certainty) that posted questions do not always faithfully present the language used by the prob composer.


first you have to choose one of the four wheels and then you have to choose one of the even digits, and then you have to continue.

The problem is that you don't need to choose a wheel in any special order. We can just simply fill each wheel with one of the even digits.
So that, giving us 5 possible digits (0, 2, 4, 6, 8) to choose from for each wheel, the combinations of valid codes is $ 5 \times 4 \times 3 \times 2 = 120 $. And further the probability of getting the correct code is:
$ \frac{\text{Valid combinations}}{\text{Total combinations}} = \frac{120}{10,000} = 0.012 $

This is wrong: "...Knowing also that the correct code only has even digits without repeating?...".  See the last paragraph of the answer of Misha Lavrov.

@user2661923 Ahh? Maybe the condition “even digits without repeating” is correct? I don't get what you wanted to say

Presumably, the original poster knows that there are only $~5!~$ (equally likely) satisfying passwords, of which the original poster must choose one at random.  The probability of choosing the correct password is therefore $~1/(5!).$

@ user2661923 Hmm.. I think, in this problem, the lock only uses 4 wheels, not all 5 digits. And, choosing 4 digits from the 5 even digits, without repetition. So, my answer is the same.

Think again, and read the last paragraph of the answer of Misha Lavrov.  In order for your answer to be correct, there must be some analytical error in the answer of Misha Lavrov.  If so, what is that error?
